# Ionic back button align to right of the header

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

How can I align or position the back button on the right side of the header?
Some body suggested to insert the back button inside navigation buttons container, but it didn't worked and the header desepeared...

Didn't worked:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"></ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Comment: where you are giving nav buttons? inside nav-bar or out side ?

Comment: Inside the nav-bar...

Comment: keep out side of nav-bar..it will work

Comment: get 'Controller ‘ionNavBar’, required by directive ‘ionNavBackButton’, can’t be found! ' exception

Comment: can you remove nav-back-button from nav-button and use it separately and check

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the following **CSS** to the class `button-clear`

```
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
```

Comment: Worked for me, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I read on Ionic Forum:

> The key is to put the ion-nav-back-button inside the ion-nav-buttons
>   and AFTER your other buttons.

So here's the solution they gave:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Also here's a working example on codepen: http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/nfkIp

Comment: As I said i tried that solution, but when you insert the back button insode nav buttons container...the header is broken...